# jquery slider output in real time

Tags: jquery, input, slider, output

I have this code: [MyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jevniky/m6qJC/1/)

HMTL

```
<p>Money: <span id="amountDisp">500</span><div id="amount_slider"></div></p><p>Time: <span id="timeDisp">7</span><div id="time_slider"></div></p><p>Calculated <span id="result" >545</span></p>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#amount_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 500,
        max: 4999,
        value: 500,
        step: 1,
                animate: true,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#amount").text(ui.value);
            calculate();
        },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#amountDisp").text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#time_slider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 7,
        max: 28,
                step: 7,
        value: 7,
                animate: true,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#time").text(ui.value);
            calculate();
        },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#timeDisp").text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    function calculate() {
        var amount = parseInt($("#amount_slider").slider("value"));
        var time = parseInt($("#time_slider").slider("value"));
                var coeficient = 0;
                switch(time){
                       case 7: coeficient = 0.09;break;
                       case 14: coeficient = 0.15;break;
                       case 21: coeficient = 0.19;break;
                       case 28: coeficient = 0.25;break;
                       }
        var rate = amount + (amount * coeficient);
        $("#result").text(rate.toFixed(2));
        $("#result_field").val(rate.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

1) It basically does what I want. BUT, I'd like to make the "calculated" field (or output) more smooth. So it will change it's value AS I slide. Like the other two outputs above sliders do.

2) And another question is, how to make this for . I mean that the inputs will be entered by user inside of typical form input. And it will also calculate.

Comment: Could you please formulate part 2 a bit clearer? Or maybe move it to a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount_field").val(ui.value);
        $("#amountDisp").text(ui.value);
                calculate();
    }
```

You need to calculate in slide event.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/m6qJC/5/)

Comment: thx :)
and one more problem. Try to move slider fast to the lowest value, and look what "Calculated: " shows. Is there a way, to make it more... I don't know.. focused? To get really those values that are set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to code your logic in `slide` callback function for real time update, not in `change`.

Concerning your second question, set a better jsfiddle with this new statement. I know, it'll take you few minutes but better to take your own time than taking time of other members...

Comment: Hi, well I don't know how to do it, that's why I ask. Here is my lame try :) http://jsfiddle.net/m6qJC/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
 change: function (event, ui) {
            $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#time").text(ui.value);
            calculate();
        },
 slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#timeDisp").text(ui.value);
        }
```

You need this:

```
 change: function (event, ui) {
            $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#time").text(ui.value);
        },
 slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
            $("#timeDisp").text(ui.value);
            calculate(); //move calculate on SLIDE event, which is triggered on every mousemove
        }
```

Do it for BOTH sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want the slider value to update in real time use input function instead of change function example below:

```
$("#time_slider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 7,
    max: 28,
            step: 7,
    value: 7,
            animate: true,
    input: function (event, ui) {
        $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
        $("#time").text(ui.value);
        calculate();
    },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#time_field").val(ui.value);
        $("#timeDisp").text(ui.value);
    }
});
```